# Optimización de queries en Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Si es bien sabido por todos las limitaciones de Access, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de poder optimizar la siguiente query sobre una tabla de Access de menos de 1 millón de registros:

```
select count(numero), sum(importe), month(fechat)
from miTabla
where numero not in (
    select numero
    from miTabla
    where '20'&day(fechat) = 2018 
    and codigo in ('8102058', '9110057', '9110004', '9110028', '9110029', 
    '6532786', '6370362', '8010071', '9912016')
    ) 
or numero not in (
    select numero
    from miTabla
    where '20'&day(fechat) = 2018 and len(codigo) <= 2 
) and '20'&day(fechat) = 2018
group by numero, month(fechat)
```

Comment: Está bien que Access no sea tan brillante como otros manejadores de base de datos, pero un millón de registros no es demasiado. Yo he visto sistemas montados en Access totalmente, interfaz incluida, que llevan años funcionando y lo hacen muy bien. Es cierto que debes preocuparte por optimizar la consulta, pero así a simple vista pocos podemos decirte sobre si la consulta está o no optimizada, porque eso depende de muchísimas cosas. Por ejemplo: ¿tienen las tablas los índices, tipos de datos, restricciones ... adecuadas? ¿está bien manejada la redundancia de datos? ... y un largo etc.

Comment: Se trata de una base de datos que no puedo tocar. Lo único que puedo hacer es optimizar la consulta al máximo desgraciadamente...

Comment: Entiendo que no se pueda *tocar*, pero ¿tampoco se puede migrar? Pregunto intentando abrirte una puerta porque trabajar sobre datos bloqueados es complicado, sobre todo si hay algo que esté mal en ellos, por ejemplo que se requiera un índice y el mismo no exista. Con eso no afirmo que los datos estén mal, eso tendrías que probarlo tú (si pudieras), revisando la base de datos, qué indices requeriría, qué índices tiene, etc. En cuanto a la consulta por la que preguntas, sin entender mejor el contexto será difícil sugerirte algo. Creo que debes decir de qué tipo son los datos y lo que quieres.

Comment: Con un set de datos y la descripcion de las tablas creo que te podriamos ayudar, pero la query no parece muy logica. Le estas pidiendo (por ejemplo) que traiga los numeros que no estan sobre otra query, que apunta a la misma tabla? usualmente uno usa not in contra otra tabla. Usarlo sobre si misma, es lo mismo que ponerlo en el where.

Comment: La query tiene lógica porque son números repetidos y quiero extraer los números que en ninguna de sus repeticiones contienen los códigos. De todas formas, con tablas temporales creo que puedo solucionar, aunque ahora tengo un problema de "[Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] No se puede actualizar. Base de datos u objeto de sólo lectura. (-1809)". Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No puedo probar esta consulta, porque no tengo tu base de datos, pero espero que funcione.

```
SELECT count(numero), sum(importe), month(fechat) as f1
FROM miTabla
WHERE '20'&day(fechat) <> 2018 
AND ( codigo not in ('8102058', '9110057', '9110004', '9110028', '9110029', 
    '6532786', '6370362', '8010071', '9912016')
   )
OR NOT (
        AND len(codigo) <= 2
        AND '20'&day(fechat) <> 2018
))
GROUP BY numero, f1
```

Según como funcionan los operadores lógicos en SQL, esta consulta debería funcionar. Si alguien ve un error en la lógica, es libre de corregir la respuesta.
Con esta consulta no estas utilizando ninguna subconsulta así que intuyo que debería ser más eficiente.